# Importing Victor.js in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module

I'm trying to use the [victor.js](http://victorjs.org/) library in a TypeScript project (3.0.1) and I'm having real heartache trying to import and use it. I've installed it from npm along with it's typings (victor @types/victor). I've tried to import it a myriad of ways but can't seem to get it to import along with type resolution in my IDE.

I've tried these:

```
import { Victor} from 'victor';  
import * as v from 'victor';
```

*(This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export)*

```
import Victor = require('victor');
```

*(works but not compatible when targeting ecmascript modules)*

```
const Victor = require("victor");
```

*(Imports validly and I can construct objects but none of the typings are present)*

I'm sure someone out there has run into a similar situation to this before. If it helps the top of the index.js of victor has the line:

```
exports = module.exports = Victor;
```

Comment: Did you try `import Victor from 'victor';`?

Comment: @MTCoster, that gives me: "module has no default export".

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### In Brief

You're trying to use `victor` as if it were an es6 module, but it is not. I see two options:

1. Let `tsc` convert your modules to a format like `commonjs`, in which case `tsc` will provide necessary glue logic between `victor` and your code
2. Or you need to load your application through a module loader that provides the glue.

#### Detailed Explanation

When I run the latest `tsc` with the import that you show, the error I get is:

> This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.

When I turn on `esModuleInterop`, then it works just fine. Here is the test code I've used:

```
import Victor from "victor";

const foo = new Victor(1, 2);
console.log(foo.y);
```

And the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

The issue originates due to the fact that when you do `import Victor from "victor"` you are asking for the value that would be exported through an `export default...` statement, which is a syntax provided by es6 modules. However, `victor` does export anything that corresponds to `export default...`. So something has to bridge the gap. With what I've shown above, when you compile, `tsc` emits this:

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
exports.__esModule = true;
var victor_1 = __importDefault(require("victor"));
var foo = new victor_1["default"](1, 2);
console.log(foo.y);
```

Note the `__importDefault` helper function. It is used whenever the TS code wants to access what a module exports as `export default...` What it does is check whether the module claims to be an es6 module. An es6 module that wants to export a default value is already correctly structured so there's nothing to do if the module is an es6 module. If the module is not an es6 module, then the helper creates a kind of fake module whose default exported value is the value of the original module.

There's an important caveat since you mention "targeting ecmascript modules". If you use, this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "es6"
  }
}
```

Then the emitted code is:

```
import Victor from "victor";
var foo = new Victor(1, 2);
console.log(foo.y);
```

Note that there is no longer any helper function. It is up to the module loader which will load the modules for your application to provide the same logic as provided by `__importDefault`. If I rename the file to have the `mjs` extension and run:

```
$ node --experimental-modules test.mjs
```

I get this output:

```
(node:18394) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
2
```

When using Node with the experimental module support, it provides the same functionality as `__importDefault`.

---

When you just use `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` without using `esModuleInterop` you are telling the compiler to *assume* that there will be something in your toolchain that will do the work of `__importDefault`. So the compiler does not provide a helper. It allows the compilation to proceed, but *you* are responsible later to use a module loader that will perform the same work as `__importDefault`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Both options for a solution are minimally palatable though haha. As a final question, do you know what module format Victor.js is using that triggers this situation? Commonjs with no default export maybe?

Comment: My pleasure. Yes, it is plain CommonJS. CommonJS does not distinguish a "default" export like es6 modules do. And the authors of Victor.js did not code the glue necessary to make Victor.js look like an es6 module (export an `__esModule` set to `true`, etc).

Comment: What a nice explanation! Beautiful

Answer (score 16):

I see there has already been excellent answers but would like to add this shorter answer.

Error message: `This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.ts(2497)`

I had this problem with importing when moving from es5 to es6 (and javascript to typescript) when converting my own javascript file to typescript.

Importing like `import * as File from "./MyFile"` in OtherFile.ts .

In MyFile.ts file I had `export = {funcName}` at the end.

The solution was to remove `=` like this `export {funcName}` from the MyFile.ts file.

*(Hope this helps someone, first time trying to make an answer for a an error/problem)*

Answer (score 4):

I feel your heartache, In that I spent a large amount of time debugging various errors on **how to write typescript definition files for existing javascript modules** and finally got to what I thought was the final hurdle when I got stuck on the same error:

> This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by
>   turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its
>   default export

The javascript in question [here](https://github.com/ghdna/athena-express/blob/27125640522b62134d25309c441b881fc66c38e0/lib/athenaExpress.js):

```
module.exports = class AthenaExpress { ...more code.. }
```

`tsconfig.json` for the compiling/"Working version" <sup>1</sup>:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "include": [
    "**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

"Working version" of the `d.ts` file with some import differences <sup>2</sup>:

```
declare module 'athena-express' {
    import * as aws from "aws-sdk";
    interface ConnectionConfigInterface {
        aws: typeof aws,
        s3: string,
        getStats: boolean
    }
    interface QueryResultsInterface {
        Items: any[],
        DataScannedInMB: number,
        QueryCostInUSD: number,
        EngineExecutionTimeInMillis: number,
        Count: number,
    }

    interface QueryInterface {
        sql: string,
        db: string,
    }

    type QueryResult = QueryResultsInterface

    interface AthenaExpressInterface {
        new: (config: ConnectionConfigInterface) => any,
        query: (query: QueryInterface) => QueryResult,
    }

    class AthenaExpress {
        new: (config: ConnectionConfigInterface) => any;
        constructor(config: ConnectionConfigInterface);
        query: (query: QueryInterface) => QueryResult;
    }
}
```

Version  of the `d.ts` file that received the same error, even when `esModuleInterop` was enabled, I also fiddled around with `module` and `target` to no avail. With import statement differences <sup>3</sup>:

```
import * as aws from "aws-sdk";
interface ConnectionConfigInterface {
    aws: typeof aws,
    s3: string,
    getStats: boolean
}
interface QueryResultsInterface {
    Items: any[],
    DataScannedInMB: number,
    QueryCostInUSD: number,
    EngineExecutionTimeInMillis: number,
    Count: number,
}

interface QueryInterface {
    sql: string,
    db: string,
}

type QueryResult = QueryResultsInterface

interface AthenaExpressInterface {
    new: (config: ConnectionConfigInterface) => any,
    query: (query: QueryInterface) => QueryResult,
}

declare class AthenaExpress {
    new: (config: ConnectionConfigInterface) => any;
    constructor(config: ConnectionConfigInterface);
    query: (query: QueryInterface) => QueryResult;
}

export = AthenaExpress
```

**notes:**

The definition file location and the file I was trying to get working with the definition:

```
 tree src/backend/js
    src/backend/js
        ├── athena-express.d.ts
        └── helloworld.ts
```

1. "Working Version" meaning `tsc` seemed to compile without complaint
2. In helloworld.ts `import {AthenaExpress} from "athena-express";`
3. In helloworld.ts `import * as AthenaExpress from "./athena-express";`