# Creating / fixing declaration file for node-json2html in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I tried to make a declaration file for node-json2html, however using `import` to import the package instead of require creates an error.
I believe that the deceleration file that I created is wrong.

The package can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json2html

## typescript

## javascript

I tried to change the declaration file several times.

The deceleration file:

```
declare module "node-json2html" {
    class json2html {
        static version: string;
        static transform(data: string, transform: J2Htransform, _options?: J2Hoptions): string | J2Htransform;
        static toText(html: string): string;
    }
    interface J2Hoptions { [x: string]: any; events: boolean; }
    interface J2Htransform {
        '<>'?: string,
        text?: string,
        html?: J2Htransform[] | string,
        [x: string]: string | Function | J2Htransform[] | undefined
    }


    function _isArray(obj: any): boolean;
    function _transform(obj: any, transform: object, options: J2Hoptions): J2Htransform;
    function _extend(options: J2Hoptions, _options: J2Hoptions): J2Hoptions;
    function _apply(obj: object, transform: J2Htransform, index: number, options: J2Hoptions): J2Htransform;

}
```

The import command:

```
import {json2html} from 'node-json2html';
```

The function that uses the package:

```
private async movieListToJson(movies: Array<Movie>): Promise<string> {
        const data: string = JSON.stringify(movies);
        const transform = { "<>": "div", "html": "<ul><li>id: ${id}</li><li>name: ${name}</li><li>image adress: ${imageAdress}</li><li>score: ${score}</li><li>page url: ${pageUrl}</li></ul>" };
        return '<h1>Movie list:</br></h1>' + json2html.transform(data, transform);
    }
```

problem: "Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined"

Full error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
    at MovieManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:196:96)
    at step (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:39:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:20:53)
    at C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:14:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:10:12)
    at MovieManager.movieListToJson (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:191:16)
    at MovieManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:80:51)
    at step (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:39:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\trfac\Documents\Projects\JS\movies\dist\movieManager.js:20:53)
(node:6644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined* is a runtime error. So first off all we have to fix that before looking at the types.

On the [usage instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json2html#usage) of the package we see this:

```js
var json2html = require('node-json2html');
```

This means that the whole module is actually `json2html`. It doesn't have a named export `json2html`.

Therefore you have to change your import to:

```js
import * as json2html from 'node-json2html';
```

or this, with `esModuleInterop` enabled:

```js
import json2html from 'node-json2html';
```

Now the runtime error should go away. Of course we have to adjust the types accordingly. To do this, add an `export =` statement to the module declaration:

```js
declare module "node-json2html" {
    class json2html {
        static version: string;
        static transform(data: string, transform: J2Htransform, _options?: J2Hoptions): string | J2Htransform;
        static toText(html: string): string;
    }
    // ...
    export = json2html;
}
```

Comment: I got a new error:
```
This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and referencing its default export.
```

*I set the tarted property at the tsconfig to es6 & "esModuleInterop": true.
I still get the error, I try to solve it now base on the info here:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701255/importing-victor-js-in-typescript>

Comment: Hmm strange, I didn't have any issue when trying it out locally. You can try enabling `esModuleInterop` in the TypeScript compiler options and then using `import json2html from 'node-json2html'`